# tengoun boton que realiza una accion como hago que al finalizar la accion se ejecute otro boton automaticamente

Tags: php, javascript, funciones, function

tengo un botón que toma un pantallazo(screenshot) de un div al dar click a un botón ese div tiene un fotmulario que al dar click en el botón guardar se guarda por submit en mysql pero me gustaria que al dar click a el boton de capturar(botón de screenshot) ejecute la funcion suya y luego la del submit,
e intentado con onsubmit="ejemplo();" en el form pero nose sirve y ponerle al botón guardar onclick="screenshot();" pero no sirve tampoco solo toma la captura no guarda o viceversa  gracias por la ayuda de antemano

mi codigo de insertar:

```html
<?php

$conn= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","prueba");
$resultado = "";
$nombre=@$_POST["nombre"];
$cedula=@$_POST["cedula"];
$telefono=@$_POST["telefono"];
if (isset ($_POST['submit'])){
   
 
    $strSQL = "INSERT into datosUsuario(nombre,cedula,telefono) values ('$nombre','$cedula','$telefono')";

    $verificar_cedula = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * From datosUsuario where cedula = '$cedula'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($verificar_cedula)>0 ){
        echo'esta cedula ya se ha ingresado';
        exit;
    }
    $verificar_telefono = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * From datosUsuario where telefono = '$telefono'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($verificar_telefono)>0 ){
        echo'esta telefono ya se ha ingresado';
        exit;
    }


    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $strSQL);

    if($query){
      $resultado = "exitoso";
    }else{
      $resultado = "error";
    }
}

?>
```

```html
 este es el form:
  
  
  
  <div class="top-img" id="top-img">
        
            <form  action="index.php" method="post" name="submit">
            <div class="container">
            <div class="formulario">

            <br><br>
<div class="col-md-12">


 <input type="text" name="nombre"required id="nombre"autocomplete="off"onkeypress="return soloLetras(event)" placeholder="ingrese un nombre...">
 </div>
 <br><br>

<div class="col-md-12">

<input type="text" name="cedula"required id="cedula"autocomplete="off"onkeypress="return valida(event)" placeholder="ingrese la cedula...">
 
 </div>
 <br><br>
 <div class="col-md-12">
<input type="text"name="telefono"required id="telefono"autocomplete="off"onkeypress="return valida(event)" placeholder="telefono..">
<br><br>
<button  class="btn btn-primary" id="boton-descarga">Descargar certificado</button>

<button  id="btn" hidden>Enviar</button>
</div>


            </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

```js
este es el codigo que crea el pantallazo:



<script>
  function downloadCanvas(canvasId, filename) {
    // Obteniendo la etiqueta la cual se desea convertir en imagen
    var domElement = document.getElementById(canvasId);
 
    // Utilizando la función html2canvas para hacer la conversión
    html2canvas(domElement, {
        onrendered: function(domElementCanvas) {
            // Obteniendo el contexto del canvas ya generado
            var context = domElementCanvas.getContext('2d');
 
            // Creando enlace para descargar la imagen generada
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = domElementCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            link.download = filename;
 
            // Chequeando para browsers más viejos
            if (document.createEvent) {
                var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
                // Simulando clic para descargar
                event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0,
                    false, false, false, false,
                    0, null);
                link.dispatchEvent(event);
            } else {
                // Simulando clic para descargar
                link.click();
            }
        }
    });
}
 
// Haciendo la conversión y descarga de la imagen al presionar el botón
$('#boton-descarga').click(function() {
    downloadCanvas('top-img', 'certificado.png');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Estimado, favor añade el código que ya tienes.

Comment: Te recomendamos agregar tu codigo para poder ayudarte. Checa el manual de Como preguntar [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Comment: necesito que un botón haga las 2 cosas la función de captura y luego de que capture haga el submit gracias

Comment: Ya probo function FUNCION1(){setTimoeut(function(){//LLAMADA FUNCION 2},100);}

Comment: prueba con los trigger https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_trigger.asp,basicamente es $(identificador).trigger(evento)

Comment: como uso el : FUNCIONn 1(){setTimoeut(function(){//LLAMADA FUNCION 2},100);} puede poner un ejemplo? o algo asi gracias

Comment: esque el boton es un type="submit" y ocupo ese mismo botón primero me descargue el archivo y luego me realice el ingreso ala base de datos y luego me redirija a otra pagina, eso lo tengo con 2 botones uno para cada accion pero me gustaria que lo hicera solo 1

Comment: si he utilizado los eventos de echo use el onclick para la funcion de screenshot pero el php de guardar en la base no es una funcion entonces no puedo asignarle un evento o si?